# Confusion about multivariable chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let $F: U \subset\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}, G: V \subset \mathbb{R^m} \to \mathbb{R^p} $ be differentiable functions on their domain.

It is well known that the chain rule says:

$$D(G \circ F)(a) = DG(F(a)) \circ DF(a)$$

However, to calculate this, we can do:

$$ DG(F(a)) \circ DF(a) = JG(F(a)) . JF(a)$$

where $JG(F(a)), JF(a)$ denote the jacobian matrices of $DG$ respectively $DF$ evaluated in $F(a)$ respectively $a$.

Can someone explain me why the last equality is true?

Comment: Sorry, what is $JG(.)$?

Comment: The jacobian matrix (I edited my post to explain)

Comment: Matrices exist in order to describe linear transformations concisely. And matrix multiplication is defined so that "the matrix of the composition is the product of the matrices".

Comment: Yes, I know that $$[f \circ g] = [f].[g]$$ but how is that relevant here? In one line, we see a composition of 2 linear transformations, in the next line, a multiplication of 2 matrices.

Comment: @Math_QED the composition of $2$ linear transformations *IS* matrix multiplication.

Comment: The equation is not strictly correct because on the left we have a linear transformation and on the right we have a matrix. It would be better to say that the matrix on the right represents the linear transformation on the left.

Comment: @littleO the definition of derivative may just be the matrix of partial derivatives (jacobian) in the case of OP (I've seen this before,) since if one works just with $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ there is a somewhat canonical way to construct the derivataive, identifying it (maybe by abuse of notation) with matrix representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic intuition is that derivatives are linear approximations for a function. For vector valued functions, these correspond to linear transformations. In particular, we can represent the derivative with matrices. It turns out that in a particularly nice basis (standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively) the best linear approximation is exactly the jacobian.

However, the key insight now, is that function composition for linear maps *is* exactly matrix multiplication.

This can be seen in a fairly down to earth way.

For two functions $f,g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, the derivatives $f^{\prime}, g^{\prime}$ are linear transformations, but this is just scalar multiplication. But to really imagine these as genuinely linear at each $(x,f(x))$, you have to imagine that they are linear in the sense that the point $(x,f(x))$ is the origin of a linear map. So, $(f \circ g)^{\prime}:=f^{\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)$ which is equivalent to saying "scalar multiplication."

For $f,g: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, we do a similar thing, but now the linear maps are not scalar multiplication, but instead linear maps, which can be given by a $2 \times 2$ matrix, which is exactly the jacobian. In a similar manner, if you go through with the algebra, you will see that the composition of two matrix functions is exactly multiplication.